# Anagram test using C++ having compile time error

Tags: c++, sorting

Please help me to find out the reason for given compilation errors. If you think there is something wrong then please suggest it to me, as I'm new to programming.

Compilation error:

```
[Error] request for member 'size' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'char [10]'
[Error] request for member 'size' in 'b', which is of non-class type 'char [10]'
```

my code is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int m,n;

void swap(int* p,int* q)//swap
{
    int temp = *p;
    *p=*q;
    *q=temp;
}

int partition(char a[],int l,int h)//partition
{
    int pivot=a[h];
    int index=l;
    for(int i=l;i++;i<h)
    {
        if(a[i]<pivot)
        {
            swap(a[i],a[index]);
            index++;
        }
    }
    swap(a[h],a[index]);
    return(index);
}

void quick_sort(char a[],int l,int h)//sorting
{
    while(l<h)
    {
      int p_index;
      p_index=partition(a,l,h);
      quick_sort(a,p_index + 1,h);
      quick_sort(a,l,p_index - 1);
   }
}


void anargram(char a[],char b[])
{

    quick_sort(a,0,m);
    quick_sort(b,0,n);

    if(m==n)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<m;k++)
        {
            if(a[k]!=b[k])
            {
                cout<<"NO\n";
            }

        }
        cout<<"YES\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"NO\n";;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"enter the strings";
    char a[10],b[10];

        cin>>a;
        cin>>b;

    m = strlen(a);
    n= strlen(b);
    anargram(a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C-style arrays don't provide any member functions, as these are primitive types (hence the compiler error).

For such an array you can use `sizeof(a)` to determine it's actual size within the same scope of it's declaration though.
As soon it's [*decayed to a pointer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying), you cannot determine the actual size from it.

---

As yours are most probably used to represent C-style NUL terminated strings, and you  probably want to use their actual size from the input, you can also use

```
char a[10],b[10];

cin>>a;
cin>>b;

m = strlen(a);
n= strlen(b);
```

---

I'd recommend rather to use

```
std::string a(10,0),b(10,0);
```

instead.

Comment: but size of array will always be 10 as it is character array of size 10..then how will i get to know the no. of characters entered by the use

Comment: It's important to note that even though you can use `sizeof` on an array to get its size (in bytes!) it will not work as soon as the array decays to a pointer, which it will do in many cases, most commonly when passed as arguments to functions.

Comment: @skvatss You could terminate it as a string, and then use `strlen` to get the length.

Comment: @skvatss Yes, that's what's the purpose of the `10` given as the template/constructor parameter of `std::array<>`, `std::vector` respectively.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg can u plss provide me with the code.. m not getting it..and thankss for pointing out my mistakes..:)

Comment: m using DEV C++ compiler

Comment: @skvatss No, we're not going to provide you with a fixed version of your code (at least I won't do so). We've given you the information you need to fix it, isn't that fairly enough? And write proper english sentences using complete words please. I'm an old fart and hate 1337.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thankss fr reminding me sir!! :) i will try to find it by my own...but if still i get struck i m gonna ask u only..

Comment: @skvatss Edited my answer to make it clearer for you dude.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sir i made the changes as told by you.but when i run the program it crashes.compilation errors are fixed

Comment: @skvatss Yeah,well, that means you have other errors in your code. Start up your program in the debugger and find them. And please don't call me sir please, I'm an old fart punk, and don't like it, OK?